# How do you prove that for all real numbers c, there always exists a value n, in which $4^n > c3^n$?

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, real-numbers

What we have so far, its $\frac{4^n}{ 3^n} > c,$ such that $\left(\frac{4}{3}\right) ^ n > c.$ From that I know that it is true, but I don't really know how to prove it formally.

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: Since $4^3=64>54=2\cdot3^3$, one knows that $4^n>2^{n/3}\cdot3^n$ for every positive $n$ hence $2^{n/3}>c$ suffices for every $c\geqslant1$, that  is, $2^n>c^3$, or equivalently, $$n>3\log_2c.$$

Comment: Please don't use various "proof-" tags just because something needs to be proved. proof-verification is for checking a proof that you already have; proof-theory is an advanced area of mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $n$ is a positive integer then
$$\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^n  =\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\right)^n\ge 1+\frac{n}{3}$$ (Bernoulli Inequality).

Answer (score 1):

For non-positive $c$'s this is trivial. So let $c>0$. Then, we know by the Archimedean property that there is some $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that:

$$\frac1{n_0} < \frac{\log(4/3)}{\log c}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.

If $c\leq0$, then the result is clear.

If $c>0$, then you may take
$$
n>\frac{\ln c}{\ln(4/3)}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

We want $$4^{n} > c3^{n} = \frac{4^n}{3^n} > c = (\frac{4}{3})^n > c $$

By using the relationship between exponential functions and log, we can get $$ n > log_\frac{4}{3} c$$

So now, for any ***c*** that you pick, you can always find ***n*** such that $$ n > log_\frac{4}{3} c$$ which will satisfy the original equation.

QED

Answer (score 0):

If $x\geq 1$ then $\frac{4}{3}\cdot x = x +\frac{1}{3}x \geq x+\frac{1}{3}$.
Hence $\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^n \cdot 1 \geq 1+\frac{1}{3}n$ for all $n>0$.